# How secure and reliable is it to store huge data in session for redirect purpose?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on php project where i need to pass data during redirect to result.php . How secure is this approach or can some please provide for me a better alternative

```
if($_POST['mygender'] && $_POST['sgender'] && $_POST['country'] && $_POST['town']){
  $sgender= $_POST['sgender'];
  $country= $_POST['country'];
  $town= $_POST['town'];
  $startage=$_POST['startage'];
  $endage=$_POST['endage'];

    $x=$functions->getX($country,$sgender,$town,$startage,$endage,$session_uid);

if($x){
   /*How secure and perfomance effect is this line*/
  $_SESSION['found']=$x;
  header("Location:result.php");
}
else{
  $reg_error="<span class='error' style='color:red;'>No match found</span>";
}
```

}

considering that $x is the db result?

I want to use the data stored in session to display the result

```
<div class="search-list">
      <?php $profile=$_SESSION['found'];
      foreach ($profile as $key => $value) : ?>
      <div class="four columns">
        <div class="search-item">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="<?php echo $base_url."uploads/".$value['profile_bg'];?>" alt="Avatar">
          </div>
          <div class="search-meta">
            <h5 class="author"><a href="#"><?php echo $value['first_name']." ".$value['last_name'];?></a></h5>
            <p class="date"><?php echo $value['birthday']."  |".$value['relationship']."  |".$value['hometown']."  |".$value['location'];?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="search-body">
            <p><?php echo $value['bio'];?></p>
          </div>
          <p><a href="profile.html" class="small button radius secondary"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i> View profile</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
       <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: 7 strings of probably less than 100 chars each is not "huge" data.

Comment: My concern is the database will grown to in size with time. Will this approach be alright to use?

Comment: Interesting that you use the word "database" but don't want to use an actual database.

Comment: @developerwjk It is quite possible that `$functions->getX` performs a search query based on the passed criteria, returning a list of, for example, users and their associated data.

Comment: The question is unclear. If you are putting this stuff in both the db and session, why? I don't get what you're doing or what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is perfectly okay assuming you are storing session data on your server and not in a cookie (which is default behaviour). 
I would say that you should be regenerating a new session after every use.

The question becomes how much data are you storing? (since the data is being stored on your server)
If it is a lot you can push it back to the client via a cookie, then just read the cookie data back... However your server will use up more bandwidth per request which is bad for scalability (if you care, I doubt it since you are in fact using php).

Comment: Creating a new session id after every request is no more secure than not doing so in reality if you aren't storing the IP and user-agent and verifying them on subsequent requests. If you changed the session id on my last request 10 seconds ago, and someone steals that session cookie, they can still easily get in due to you not checking the IP/user-agent pair. So its just a crappy attempt at security by obscurity basically. And in my estimation completely unnecessary with proper session hijacking checks.